# how to update today's date in datepickerrange() in dashboard without re-running the python code?

Tags: plotly-dash

I am using dcc.DatePickerRange() where I set end date to be today, if I share my dashboard with others and I don't re-run the python code, how do I update today's date? Thanks

```
dcc.DatePickerRange(id='date-range',
                   min_date_allowed=datetime(2020,1,1),
                   max_date_allowed=datetime.today(),
                   start_date=start_date,  
                   end_date=datetime.today(),
                   )
```

Comment: I think this is something you wan to find, just need to tweak a little to make it return the updated component as the page refresh. https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates#updates-on-page-load

Comment: Thanks Caleb, yes using dcc,Interval() works. Thanks